# How to get Jenkins ssh publickey?

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 machines:

machine A: contains nodejs environnment,
machine B: contains Jenkins server.

Jenkins listen for GitHub push, and then make ssh access to machine B and pull the code and then run the code. 
here I need to subscribe Jenkins server public key to machine A, 
I know is it possible to get the public key from Jenkins server terminal, but I don't have access to the server, I can just log to the web dashboard.

is it possible to get the public key from the web dashboard?

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly but do you want to get jenkins's public key by dashboard to copy it to machine A?

Comment: yes exactly :) ,

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Script Console. And you can use any shell command e.g.
[image]

`"cat /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa.pub".execute().text`

Comment: I dont have access to this page

Comment: You can try also create job which will be executing similiar command in the build section.

Comment: Why not post the excerpt as text so we can copy it? >:(